# MKV to MP4 (AAC and TrueHD Atmos)

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following syntax to convert MKV to MP4 with **AAC 6ch** & **DTS-HD MA 8ch** with zero issues.

```
ffmpeg -i "Movie (2022).mkv" -c copy -map 0:? -strict -2 "Movie (2022).mp4"
```

What is the syntax to allow for **AAC 6ch** & **TrueHD Atmos 8ch**?

Comment: In the command line you were using `-c copy` to copy all streams - that means: if `input.mkv` has that type of audio then the `output.mp4` will have it as well. The same command line should still work for `input.mkv` with other type of audio you mentioned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don’t think you can just convert something do Dolby Atmos. It’s not channel-based like “lesser” audio formats but rather object-based. // According to the MP4 Registry Authority, Dolby Atmos is not yet supported in MP4 containers.

Comment: -c copy will copy it, but convert it to some weird format (not one to one). @Daniel, it might be a limitation of the MP4 container, thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ffmpeg to copy AAC from mkv but can not for TrueHD streams to mp4.
you can add later the TrueHD streams to mp4 using mp4box.
Stage:

1. I recommended to extract all streams using mkvcleaver from mkv.
2. Mux the video streams, and aac/dts streams using ffmpeg
   or better dd+ (ec3,ac3,aac) using mp4muxer into mp4
   dolby mp4muxer from github is necessary for maintaining Dolby Vision / Dolby Atmos detection.
3. Mux added with mp4box for lossless subs like truehd(no ac3 core)
   and some internal SRT subtitles with mp4box.

Stage 2,3 can be automatically using Dovi_script (mp4box, and mp4muxer included)
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1X4WmMsaBO6a4OIY_8iFjeBL2KFZWTqKr
Pick way number 8-1-1

Stage 2,3 manual using mp4muxer and mp4box
https://github.com/DolbyLaboratories/dlb_mp4base/tree/master/bin

Example for non dolby vision stream & dolby atmos truehd:

```
mp4muxer.exe -i Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater_Track01.h264 -i Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater_Track02.ac3  -o Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater.mp4

MP4Box.exe -add Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater.mp4:rate=0 -add dolby.ac3 -add "Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater.mkv_ - 2 - TrueHD (Atmos), 7.1 channels, 48kHz.thd":disable  -brand mp42isom -ab dby1 -no-iod Dolby_Conductor_Lossless_ATMOS-thedigitaltheater_TrueHD_AC3.mp4
```

For Dolby Vision you need info profile of the streams (via mediainfo check)

```
 --dv-profile <arg>                 = Sets the Dolby Vision profile. This option is MANDATORY for
                                      DoVi elementary stream: Valid profile values are:
                                      4 - dvhe.04, BL codec: HEVC10; EL codec: HEVC10; BL compatibility: SDR/HDR.
                                      5 - dvhe.05, BL codec: HEVC10; EL codec: N/A;    BL compatibility: None.
                                      7 - dvhe.07, BL codec: HEVC10; EL codec: HEVC10; BL compatibility: Blue-ray HDR10.
                                      8 - dvhe.08, BL codec: HEVC10; EL codec: N/A;    BL compatibility: SDR/HDR.
                                      9 - dvav.09, BL codec: AVC;    EL codec: N/A;    BL compatibility: SDR/HDR.
 --dv-bl-compatible-id <arg>        = Sets the Dolby Vision base layer compatible ID, if the profile index is 8, this option must be set by user.
 --dv-bl-compatible-id 0 is non-cross compatibility
 --dv-bl-compatible-id 1 is HDR10 cross compatibility (usually this one)
 --dv-bl-compatible-id 2 is SDR cross compatibility
 --dv-bl-compatible-id 4 is HLG cross compatibility
 --dv-bl-compatible-id 6 is Blueray cross compatibility
```

For profile 7

```
mp4muxer -i P7_FEL_GIJoe_The_Rise_of_Cobra_Track01.h265 -i P7_FEL_GIJoe_The_Rise_of_Cobra_Track02.ec3 -o P7_FEL_GIJoe_The_Rise_of_Cobra.mp4 --dv-profile 7 --mpeg4-comp-brand mp42,iso6,isom,msdh,dby1 --overwrite
```

For profile 8

```
mp4muxer -i P81_GlassBlowing2_3840x2160@59_94fps_15200kbps_Track01.h265 -i P81_GlassBlowing2_3840x2160@59_94fps_15200kbps_Track02.ec3 -o P81_GlassBlowing2_3840x2160@59_94fps_15200kbps.mp4 --dv-profile 8 --dv-bl-compatible-id 1 --mpeg4-comp-brand mp42,iso6,isom,msdh,dby1 --overwrite
```